# Open a list of directories with different names and extract a file from it?

Tags: python, merge, directory

I have different directories with different names (date) and I want to extract a file with a continent name from all of them and then merge that file for all of the dates. Can anybody tell me the most efficient way to do it in python?

I already use glob package to get into the directories. but do not know how to merge them:

```
import glob

path = '/home/Data/pb/2014-*/ank.txt.gz'

for file in glob.glob(path):
    file.readlines()
```

Comment: first of all you should not use file as the variable name ... use `for fname in glob.glob(pattern):` hopefully that gives you enough of a clue to continue your task

Comment: So you want to get a file out of each folder, and move them all into a single folder? Or create a new file that is a conglomerate of all the other files?

Comment: It would be rather surprising that you could directly read a `.gz` file line by line ... You probably need to take a look at the [gzip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) module.

Comment: @Cyber I want to move them in a single folder and of course afterwards merging them is easy also with bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
pb/2014-01-01/file_of_intereste.txt
pb/2014-02-01/file_of_intereste.txt
pb/2014-03-01/file_of_intereste.txt
...
```

First, create my test env:

```
# Created 10 files in 10 directories named 
# pb/2014-$i/file_of_interest.txt. Then 
# pushed "contents_of_file_2014-$i" into each file.

jon$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do mkdir -p pb/2014-$i; echo contents_of_file_2014-$i > pb/2014-$i/file_of_interest.txt; done



# Run the merge.py (source below)
jon$ python merge.py
# See the output
jon$ cat output.txt
contents_of_file_2014-1
contents_of_file_2014-10
contents_of_file_2014-2
contents_of_file_2014-3
contents_of_file_2014-4
contents_of_file_2014-5
contents_of_file_2014-6
contents_of_file_2014-7
contents_of_file_2014-8
contents_of_file_2014-9
```

merge.py

```
$ cat merge.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import gzip

merged_fname = "output.txt"
files = glob.glob('pb/2014-*/file_of_interest.txt')

with open(merged_fname, 'w') as merged_file_handle:
  for fname in files:
    # For gzip, use the gzip opener instead.
    # @sylvain
    #with gzip.open(fname, 'rt') as file_handle:
    with open(fname, 'r') as file_handle:
      merged_file_handle.write(file_handle.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to read .gz files, you need the [gzip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) module:

```
import glob
import gzip

path = '/home/Data/pb/2014-*/ank.txt.gz'

# loop for each file *name* matching the glob pattern
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    # open the file as a gzip compressed file
    with gzip.open(fname, 'rt') as f:
        # for each line of the file
        for data in f:
             # do whatever you need here
             # ...
```

Comment: Thanks ! why are you using wb?